# Sum the same table across different number of worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, formula

So i have an excel file where i can enter the different projects that i want to analyse and the location of the files. Then a code to go and get the files and generate 2 sheets (from a template that i created) for each project entered and populate the data. These projects can vary the name and quantity.

My problem appears when i try to do a total table. Where i would go and get from the same cell in the different sheets the value and sum them. The number of sheets can change so i didnt manage to use a sheets.count, but the name of the sheets that relevant for this operation all start by "Total_".

So the beginning of the code that i have so far is:

```
`Sub refresh()

 Parametre

    Dim nbOnglet As Integer
    Dim nbProjet As Integer
    
    Dim name As String
    Dim nametot As String
    Dim A As String
    Dim B As String
            
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim iDebut As Integer
    
    Dim values As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim dSum As Double
  
 Initialisation
    iDebut = 9

 Déterminer le nombre d'onglets du Classeur
    nbOnglet = Sheets.Count

 Déterminer le nombre de projet à traiter
    folderpath = Range("C3").Value
    Sheets("Sommaire").Select
    nbLigne = Cells(10, "A").Value

x = 0

For idx = 1 To nbLigne
     activate Récapitulatif
        Sheets("Récapitulatif").Select
        
     Define the variable name - tab name
        A = "Total_"
        B = Sheets("Sommaire").Cells(iDebut + idx, "D").Value
        name = B
        nametot = A & B`
```

Then for the sun i have tried different options but none appears to work for the entire table. I managed to get the good result for one cell by using the following:

```
x = x + sheets(nametot).range("F7").Value2
```

But couldn't do it for all the range (F7:CI31).

Other formula that i have tried was:

```
Set xRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nbLigne).Range("K7:CI31")
xRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nametot).name & "'!RC+'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nametot).name & "'!RC)"
```

Although this gives the equation that i want since it is running in a loop, it calculates the same for each sheet and stops at the last one identified... So not doing what i would like to: sum the same cell across the different sheets named 'Total_XXXX' and present the value in the 'Récapitulatif' sheet.

I have been looking around internet and i can't really figure out a way to do it.
DO you have any ideas?
Thank you so much in advance

[example of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx1oG.png)

Comment: `x = x + worksheetfunction.sum(sheets(nametot).range("F7:CI31"))` perhaps?

Comment: @SJR it didnt work... It gave the same value to all the table, and i can't see where it comes from the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Consolidate Worksheets

**Links (Microsoft Docs)**

- [Range.Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)
- [Range.Consolidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.consolidate)
- [XlConsolidationFunction Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlconsolidationfunction)

**Description**

- In the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`), the following will consolidate (in this case sum up (`xlSum`)) all the same ranges (`srcRange`) in all worksheets with names starting with a specified string (`srcLead`) into another worksheet (`tgtName`) starting from a specified cell (`tgtFirst`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub consolidateWorksheets()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const srcRange As String = "K7:CI31"
    Const srcLead As String = "Total_"
    Const tgtName As String = "Récapitulatif"
    Const tgtFirst As String = "A1"
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    
    ' Define R1C1-Style Source Ranges Address.
    Dim rcRng As String
    rcRng = tgt.Range(srcRange).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    
    ' Define Consolidation Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count)
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim ws As Worksheet         ' Current Source Worksheet
    Dim CurrentName As String   ' Current Source Worksheet Name
    Dim n As Long               ' Current Element in Consolidation Array
    
    ' Write full paths of Source Worksheets to Consolidation Array.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        CurrentName = ws.Name
        If InStr(1, CurrentName, srcLead, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            n = n + 1
            Data(n) = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & rcRng
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Validate and resize Consolidation Array.
    If n = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No worksheets to consolidate.", vbCritical, "Fail"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To n)
    
    ' Consolidate.
    tgt.Range(tgtFirst).Consolidate Sources:=Data, _
                                    Function:=xlSum
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data consolidated.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have still an error when defining data i think.
I get an error 91 on this line    
```ws.Range(tgtFirst).Consolidate Sources:=Data, Function:=xlSum```

Comment: So i managed to figure out the error. It was a question of selection of the good worksheet in this final code line (Récapitulatif). And also selecting the good range and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @novais: I'm very sorry. My bad. Replaced the last `ws` with `tgt`.